# Windows Phone XNA MediaPlayer/MediaQueue do not show the correct state for paused local media when a silverlight application is booted

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

After pausing local media (either in a silverlight app, the zune player or via system tray); when cold-launching any Silverlight application:

Expected Behaviour:

The Microsoft XNA MediaPlayer.Queue contains the appropriate media and the
player is in the paused state. MediaPlayer.GameHasControl should be true. The Zune player shows the media as expected.

Actual Behaviour:

The Microsoft XNA MediaPlayer.Queue is empty and the player is in the stopped
state. MediaPlayer.GameHasControl is sometimes in a variable state. The Zune player shows the media as expected.

Minimal reproducible code:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnMainPageLoaded;
    }

    private void OnMainPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();

        // X reports as NULL when launching the app with an XNA song in the system tray in a paused state
        // The XNA queue is empty. ActiveSongIndex is -1. PlayState is stopped.
        var x = MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong;

        // ** Debug BREAK-POINT here - check value of 'x' **
        // Following Play() below, the MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong then becomes non-null as expected
        var lib = new MediaLibrary();
        MediaPlayer.Play(lib.Songs.First());

        return;
    }
}
```

}

Note: Any boiler-plate silverlight application shows this behaviour - however, the Microsoft Zune client always seems to show the media correctly in the paused state.

My assumption that this is therefore an issue in the Silverlight XNA wrapper...

Has anyone else seen this? Is there a workaround?

Many thanks,
Jon

Comment: I've also posted this to the MSDN forum: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/102433/607779.aspx#607779

Comment: Still no luck with this.

Anyone out there? :-)

Cheers,
Jon